# C++ anonymous class with an initializer

Tags: c++, class, object, initialization

Based on this question (asked a while ago)

[inline-object-instantiation-and-transformation-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765007/inline-object-instantiation-and-transformation-in-java)

Is there a way to instantiate and object and initialize it's members in a single line of c++, without the use of a constructor?

In java, as per the link:

```
JFrame aFrame = new JFrame();
aFrame.add(new JPanel() {{
 setSize(100,100);
 setLocation(50,50);
 setBackground(Color.red);
}});
```

Can this be done in any way in c++?

EDIT: For example

```
class Foo{
  public:
    int test;
    int test2;

};

int main(){
    Foo foo(){{test=5 test2=4}};  //Like this
}
```

Comment: 3 questions: a) What anonymous class? b) "as per the link", what link? c) You ask to do something in one line and your example, well, clearly isn't a one liner. So, what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Nope. But I wish it could...

Comment: I edited the question, fixing the errors and added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one idiom that allows syntax similar to Java. As with everything, it has its downsides as well. I'll leave it up to you to figure out whether it's right for this.

```
class Foo {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

public:
    Foo &setA(int val) {a = val; return *this;}
    Foo &setB(int val) {b = val; return *this;}
    Foo &setC(int val) {c = val; return *this;}
};
```

Now you can do the following:

```
auto foo = Foo().setB(2).setA(1).setC(3);
```

You can apply it to as many or few members as desired. However, it can be tricky in some cases to ensure you always have a valid object. Required initialization can go in the constructor.

Something along these lines that might be more natural is [Boost.Parameter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html), which offers named parameter support that you can use to combine meaningful names with constructor arguments.

Answer (score 4):

If the class is an aggregate (with no base classes, non-public members, virtual functions or user-declared constuctors), then you can use aggregate initialisation to initialise its members:

```
struct thing {
    int a,b,c;
};

thing t = {1,2,3};
```

Otherwise, it can only be initialised by a constructor.

Comment: There's also the possibility of `auto something = thing().setA(foo).setB(bar).setC(baz);`, which is a bit closer to the Java code.

Comment: Can you point to or hint at why this works only for aggregates?

Comment: @chris Could this work for initializing out of order? How 'bout for virtual functions?

Comment: @Borgleader: You generally want encapsulation from non-aggregate types; exposing the data members in this way would break that encapsulation and remove your freedom to change the class internals.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Right, but what I don't understand is, if I have a class with say a user-defined ctor (that takes 3 params). If I do `Foo f { 3.0, "Blah", Colors::YELLOW };` why doesn't that just call said ctor?

Comment: @Borgleader: It does; list-initialisation uses a suitable constructor if there is one. (But note that my example specifically does aggregate initialisation, due to the `=`; it won't work if there's a constructor.)

Comment: @GCon, Yes for the first; it's just calling functions. I'm not entirely sure how you would plan on using it with virtual functions, so it depends I guess.

Comment: @chris, could you please write it out as an answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

That is not an anonymous class. An anonymous class is one without a name.

If you want an anonymous (temporary) *instance*, and you can initialize it like so:

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
    int b;
};

void bar(Foo const &);

int main() {
    bar(Foo{1,2});
}
```

See Mike's answer for the equivalent for a named instance of the named structure. The aggregate constraint is the same.